how to select a combobox without a title using pywinauto
In my windows application there are three ComboBoxes without title but different list items. How can I select right ComboBox based on the items it contains. If I only select Control_Type I am getting ElementAmbiguousError.
I am getting error :-

pywinauto.findwindows.ElementAmbiguousError: There are 3 elements that
match the criteria {'control_type': 'ComboBox', 'top_level_only':
False, 'parent': <uia_element_info.UIAElementInfo - 'ApplicationName',
MetroWindow, 591164>, 'backend': 'uia'}


from pywinauto.application import Application
from pywinauto.mouse import click
import time


# Path to the application executable
app_path = r"file path"

# Start the application
app = Application(backend='uia').start(app_path)

# Wait for the main window to appear (adjust timeout as needed)
main_window = app.window(title_re="ApplicationName")
# Now you can interact with the main window or its controls as needed
# Example: print the main window's text
print(main_window.window_text())

# Example: click a button in the main window
main_window.child_window(title="System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem", auto_id="Alarm", control_type="ListItem").click_input()
time.sleep(1)

main_window.child_window(control_type="ComboBox").click_input()


The obvious answer is to add titles to your CombBoxes.

That's not an option, that's why asked this question :)

Why is it not an option? You can clearly see from the error message that not having a title means that the findwindows function can not succeed.

Because application has already developed and validated. There are no resources to update the application. I understand the reason for error, trying to find work around if possible.

Yes, it is typically hard to change the application if you just downloaded it and you may not have access to source code and you're not a developer of it. So the question really makes sense.

The workaround is simply using found_index in search criteria:
main_window.child_window(control_type="ComboBox", found_index=0).click_input()

For your case the index could be 0, 1 or 2. You can double check which combobox you've found by method .draw_outline() instead of .click_input().
